# Webform Not Displaying on Drupal Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, owl-carousel

First off, Thanks for taking time to look at my question. I inherited control of a site and I'm stumped trying to figure out why I can't get the webform to display on 2 pages, but displays on others. I am able to edit the content on the site using "View/Edit". The js src is valid. There are no error messages displaying in inspector. My modules are updated and I believe the webform uses owl carousel.

Pages with working webform: http://emswlaw.com/mediation-form,
http://emswlaw.com/personal-injury-form

Non-displaying webform pages: http://emswlaw.com/node/119,
http://emswlaw.com/mediation-center

Any assistance to figure out why this content will not display would be greatly appreciated. The site uses Drupal 7 and I believe an update to a module may have caused this. I have little experience working with Drupal and css but not so much with js or jquery.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two links are actually webform content types while the other two are basic pages. If you want to add the block to the basic pages, change the settings to have the form as a block and add it to the additional pages.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/165820/13420